# Vertical ScrollBar override column qml

Tags: android, qml

default vertical scroll bar in tableview was override my last column in android environment but not happened in window environment and linux environment.

so can somebody tell me where i'm wrong and how to fix it

```
TableView {
    id: list
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 910
    height: 590
    anchors.rightMargin: 102
    highlightOnFocus: true
    anchors.topMargin: 34
    anchors.leftMargin: 0
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.left: parent.left
    verticalScrollBarPolicy :Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn

    z: 1

    TableViewColumn {
        id:col1
        movable : false
        role: "stt"
        title: "No."
        width: 100
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        id:col2
        movable : false
        role: "title"
        title: "Title"
        width: 400
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        id:col3
        movable : false
        role: "author"
        title: "Author"
        width:(list.width - col1.width -col2.width - 18)
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        id: col4
        movable : false
        role: "type"
        title: "Type"
        visible: false
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder why did you posted image of image viewer with image instead of posting just image itself. As for the question - did you try to set some margins?

Comment: QA give me this and i just using it

Comment: That is not how StackOverflow is working. This is not a *let others do my work* kind of site. If *folibis* is trying to help you, by suggesting things, it is your responsibility to test it out. Keep in mind, that most of us are trying to help you in our free time. If you want help, you should be cooperative and put some effort in it as well.

Comment: Maybe some of us have a valuable suggestion to you, but not the time to spare, to write a full answer. You can't *demand* answers.